# How to dynamically substitute class

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, dynamic

I have dynamic List Cars.
Each type of certain configuration settings to edit the data need different forms.

example:

type tt77, tt90 - used class CarsTT
d8080  - used class Carsd8080
d8797 - also uses this class but with different congestion.

It can be like that automate, or do I always have to use the SWITCH

```
foreach (var item in Cars)
{
    switch (item.Key)
    {
        case "tt77":
            {
                ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key, 
                    new CarsTT(item.Value, item.Value, "", "start"));
            } break;
        case "tt90":
            {
                ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key, 
                    new CarsTT(item.Value, item.Value, "", "start"));
            } break;
        case "d8080":
            {
                ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key, 
                    new Carsd8080(null, new List<string[]>()));
            } break;
        case "d8797":
            {
                ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key, 
                    new Carsd8080(item.Value));
            } break;
        default: break;
    }

}
```

Comment: How many types of cars do you have? Will you need to add new types without changing your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always create a:

```
SortedDictionary <string, ConstructorInfo> factory;
```

and then do:

```
ConfigClasses.Add (item.Key, factory [item.Key].Invoke ());
```

but you have constructors that take different parameters lists. This is a problem. You need to have the same constructor for each type<sup>1</sup>. You could package all the possible parameters into a single object and pass that as the constructor parameter, the constructor then pulls what it needs from the object.

Notes:

1. This isn't strictly true, you could make it so that the Invoke call has the required data for the constructor - the ConstructorInfo type contains a list of all the parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid the switch statement. you can however do this:

```
foreach (var item in Cars)
{
    switch (item.Key)
    {
        case "tt77":
        case "tt90":
            {
                ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key, 
                    new CarsTT(item.Value, item.Value, "", "start"));
            } break;
        case "d8080":
            {
                ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key, 
                    new Carsd8080(null, new List<string[]>()));
            } break;
        case "d8797":
            {
                ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key, 
                    new Carsd8080(item.Value));
            } break;
        default: break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphism here if the number of types is hardcoded and will not change. For example:

```
interface ICar
{
    void Configure();
}

class TT77Car : ICar
{
    public void Configure()
    {
    ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key,
                    new CarsTT(item.Value, item.Value, "", "start"));

    }
}

...

class D8797 : ICar
{
    public void Configure()
    {
    ConfigClasses.Add(
                    item.Key,
                    new Carsd8080(null, new List<string[]>()));
    }
}


//And this is how to use it
ICar car = //resolve to the car item: new Car(), via IoC or whatever
car.Configure();
```